# In GDB, can you set memory as if it were a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, gdb

Say for instance I have a 32 element unsigned char array at address 0xdeadbeef. I would like to overwrite the contents of the array in memory. I am not compiled with -g, and so cannot just do a "set [variable name] = [my value]".

Is it possible to set the contents of the memory all at once?

I've seen someone try `set *((unsigned char*) 0xdeadbeef) = "abcdefghijklmnop"`, but this doesn't appear to work.

Alternatively, if it isn't possible (for instance, because how would gdb know to convert that to the hex ascii representation?), is it possible to give multiple bytes, words, etc all at once? For example, I could just calculate the value in hex that I want the array to represent, but can I feed it all at once? Something like: `set 0xdeadbeef = 0x4142434445464748495051`

Comment: Do you not have a `memset` or `strcpy` symbol from your C library, even?

Comment: No. I am debugging through an already compiled program which I can't just re-compile. If I could do that, I definitely would use those functions :)

Comment: Right, but usually the C library is dynamically linked, so you have access to the symbol names even if the rest of the program wasn't compiled with debugging information.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. So, just have gdb call it and pass in the memory address directly, I take it? Something like this? call memcpy(0xdeadbeef, "mycharacters", [# of mycharacters])

Comment: Should work, yup.  You might need some casts in there to make everybody happy.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. For my own edification, since you mentioned it, if you have no memset or strcpy symbols (just assume no symbols for that kind of stuff at all), is this sort of operation still possible, or would you just have to take the largest type you can use and set areas of memory one by one?

Comment: You can write macros/functions in GDB. I don't know of anything off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Posting this just so the question has an "official" answer)

Carl's statements in the comments are entirely correct. You can do the following in gdb:

`call strcpy(0xdeadbeef, "mystring")`

This works for any of the functions included in the statically linked C library (memset, strncpy, etc).

Answer (score 6):

There's alternative of writing char array in one command, without standard functions like `strcpy()`.

```
set *(char [CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] *) <WRITE_ADDRESS> = "YOUR_CHAR_ARRAY"
```

where `CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE` is the size of `YOUR_CHAR_ARRAY`, plus extra NULL byte (null-terminated string).

e.g.

```
set *(char [15] *) 0x20018000 = "Write a string"
```