# How to set a double variable with integer value using GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a variable with type double and I want to set it with a integer value.

For example:

```
double x;
```

In GDB, when I do :

```
set x = 14
p x
$1 = 14 //ok, looks right
x/xg &x
0x7fffffffec28: 0x402c000000000000 //oh no, this is a double representation and I want integer!
```

What I want is to `x` have an integer value `x = 0xe` instead of a double representation even if the variable is a double.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* do you want something like that? What is the actual problem you try to solve?

Comment: I have an assembly instruction that sets a double (Floating-Point Register) with an integer value/representation ( I don't know why). The problem is, there's another instruction that uses this value and it is also expecting an integer value/ representation. I want to change this value while debugging just to see some results before I change the code

Comment: sounds like you could use `memset`, write whatever data you want into the address of `x`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064612/in-gdb-can-you-set-memory-as-if-it-were-a-char-array

Comment: In this context, how can I use `memcpy` with a constant?
I mean, both `memcpy` and `strcpy` are expecting pointers.
So `memcpy(&x, 0xe, sizeof(double))` doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I originally typed `memcpy` in error and edited my comment to `memset`, but you have a working way forward now so no matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the type of the memory location:

```
p {int}&x=10
$4 = 10
x/xg &x
0x7f2c40 <x>:   0x000000000000000a
```

Comment: I will just add that, in my case, it was `long` instead of `int` but this is only worth to mention. Thanks a lot!